# Euler Systems and Coleman’s Conjecture

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves, class-field-theory, cyclotomic-fields

I’m trying to work on Coleman’s conjecture for abelian extensions of imaginary quadratic fields. I’ve read most papers by Seo regarding circular distributions. However, I’m a still confused about what it means that “all Euler systems come from cyclotomic units in an easy way”; what does this mean and what is that easy way?

Also, what is the extend to which similar thing can be done if the field Q of rationals is replaced by an imaginary quadratic field?

Comment: I have no idea what this question means, and I've been working on Euler systems for half my career. Can you make it a bit more precise, maybe with some links and/or references?

Comment: The last paragraph of page 7 of Seo's "Circular Distributions and Euler Systems" states that "there are almost no other Euler systems except the cyclotomic units". How do I prove this? re there any other examples apart from the cyclotomic units?

Comment: With the commonly understood definition of "Euler system" (as in Karl Rubin's classic book "Euler Systems"), this assertion of Seo is simply untrue. Presumably Seo is using some other, more specific definition -- maybe he means only Euler systems for the trivial representation and $K = \mathbf{Q}$ -- but even so, the use of "almost" suggests this is supposed to be a rough guideline rather than a rigorous theorem. Soogil Seo appears to be currently mathematically active, so why don't you ask him directly what the phrase meant?

Comment: Seo actually describes cyclotomic units of an abelian number filed F and then uses these cyclotomic units to construct Euler systems of F, which then suggests that there are almost no other Euler systems except these. Is this assertion untrue?

Comment: The assertion is not precise enough to have a well-defined truth value. Maybe what Seo is aiming at is the assertion that the module of Euler systems for $K = \mathbf{Q}$ and $T = \mathbf{Z}_p(1)$ is generated by the image of the cyclotomic units under the Kummer map; this sounds plausible, and I think it may follow from the Mazur--Wiles theorem (former Iwasawa main conjecture), but I'd have to check. But there are lots of other Galois representations for which it is interesting to study Euler systems, and these other Euler systems have nothing much to do with cyclotomic units.

Comment: @david I deleted my previous comments as they had lots of typing mistakes. 
I’m trying to get the hang of how to type in mathoverflow.

Comment: I'm afraid you're probably wasting your time trying to get an answer to this question on MathOverflow. The quote you give from Seo's work is quite imprecise, as well as relying on non-standard terminology and definitions; hence it's not really possible for anyone but Seo to deduce what he meant by it. If you absolutely must know, your best bet is to contact Soogil Seo directly.

Comment: @david I know and I tried. I emailed him but hasn’t got a reply yet; I understand that he must be very busy that he hasn’t replied yet. I’m trying my best to read as many papers as possible to understand the following statement: Coleman’s conjecture concerning circular distribution imply that Euler systems over abelian number fields arise in “an elementary” way from the theory of cyclotomic units.

What is that “elementary way”? I would appreciate if you could help.

Comment: You've asked your question 3x already, you don't need to repeat it. My guess is that this sentence of Seo is intended to be an informal description of the two (related) results formally stated and proved as Theorem 4.2 and Theorem A of the same paper, both of which assert that (for the particular, nonstandard notion of "Euler system" used in op.cit.) the Euler system of cyclotomic units generates the module of all Euler systems -- i.e. any Euler system can be gotten from the cyclotomic-unit Euler system by applying an element of the ring $R$.

Comment: @DavidLoeffler The above explanation is quite helpful, however, you have said "any Euler system can be gotten from the cyclotomic unit Euler system by applying an element of the ring $R$". What does that element of $R$ look like and how doe s it act on the cyclotomic unit?

Comment: As this question came up again today, let me add that Coleman's conjecture has been proven in [this article by Bullach, Burns, Daoud, Seo](https://www.homepages.ucl.ac.uk/~ucahdbu/coleman.pdf). Probably this answers this vague question.